# From a dynamic table how can i transfer current rows value to a js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/vAYFL/4/)

here `{name}` and `{host}` gets populated by from a spry XMLDataset, and `{name}` value will be dynamic, so how can i get the current row values to be passed as a parameter to a JS function?

**eg**: When I click any of the rows `{name}` hyperlink it should get the `{host}` value and passes it to the JS function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your a tag to

```
<a href="#" class="aDg">{name}</a>
```

and then

```
$('#tableDg tbody tr td a.aDg').live('click', function(){
    alert("AD");
    alert($(this).text());
    alert($('input', $(this).parent().next()).val());
})
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vAYFL/6/)

You can use console.log instead of alerts if you use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/fx/) and extension [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 1):

When you call your show() function pass `this` - which will give the function a reference to the element that called it. Then your show() function can work its way around the DOM using properties like `parentNode`.

The following is not meant to be the prettiest or neatest way to do what you want; rather, it is a sample to get you started. For more info see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Introduction

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="show(this);">    

function show(elmnt) {
   // elmnt is the <a>
   var _td = elmnt.parentNode; // the <a> element's parent <td>
   var _tr = _td.parentNode; // the row
   var thirdTD = _tr.cells(2); // the third <td> in the <tr>
   var _input = thirdTD.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]; // the first <input> in that cell
   alert(_input.value); // the {host} value
}
```